# How can I avoid the boost::compute::zip_iterator and boost::iterators::zip_iterator confict when using boost compute and boost::range together?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, boost-range, boost-iterators, boost-compute

I'd like to use `boost::compute and boost::range` together, like below, but if I uncomment the `#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>` line I get an error saying that `boost::compute::zip_iterator` and `boost::iterators::zip_iterator` are ambiguous. Is there a way around this, so that I can use `boost::compute` and `boost::range` together in the same cpp file? I am using on Windows vs2015 64bit. Boost 1.67.0.

Update: I've found the same error occurs if I try to include `boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp` instead of `boost/range/combine.hpp`, so it is not specific to the Boost Range library.

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
//#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/functional/math.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp>

namespace compute = boost::compute;
using compute::float4_;
using compute::lambda::_1;
using compute::lambda::_2;
using compute::lambda::distance;

int main()
{
    // get default device and setup context
    compute::device device = compute::system::default_device();
    compute::context context(device);
    compute::command_queue queue(context, device);

    // generate random data on the host
    std::vector<float4_> a(10000);
    std::vector<float4_> b(10000);
    std::vector<float> r(10000);
    std::generate((float*)a.data(), (float*)(a.data() + a.size()), rand);
    std::generate((float*)b.data(), (float*)(b.data() + b.size()), rand);

    // create a vector on the device
    compute::vector<float4_> _a(a.size(), context);
    compute::vector<float4_> _b(b.size(), context);
    compute::vector<float> _r(r.size(), context);

    // transfer data from the host to the device
    compute::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), _a.begin(), queue);
    compute::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), _b.begin(), queue);

    boost::compute::transform(
        _a.begin(), _a.end(),
        _b.begin(),
        _r.begin(),
        distance(_1, _2),
        queue
    );

    // copy values back to the host
    compute::copy(_r.begin(), _r.end(), r.begin(), queue);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        float4_ va = a[i];
        float4_ vb = b[i];
        float vr = r[i];
        float e = std::sqrt(std::pow(va[0] - vb[0], 2) +
            std::pow(va[1] - vb[1], 2) +
            std::pow(va[2] - vb[2], 2) +
            std::pow(va[3] - vb[3], 2));

        std::cout << std::setprecision(12);

        if (std::abs(e - vr) > 1e-2)
            std::cout << e << " != " << vr << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: demo, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
>   1>  demo.cpp 1>  This header is implementation detail and provided for
>   backwards compatibility.
>   1>C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(67):
>   error C2668: 'boost::compute::make_zip_iterator': ambiguous call to
>   overloaded function 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp(276):
>   note: could be
>   'boost::compute::zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>
>   boost::compute::make_zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>(IteratorTuple)'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   T=boost::compute::float4_, 1>
>   IteratorTuple=boost::tuples::tuple,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>
>   1>          ] 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp(357): note: or
>   'boost::iterators::zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>
>   boost::iterators::make_zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>(IteratorTuple)'
>   [found using argument-dependent lookup] 1>          with 1>          [
>   1>              T=boost::compute::float4_, 1>
>   IteratorTuple=boost::tuples::tuple,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>
>   1>          ] 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(67): note:
>   while trying to match the argument list
>   '(boost::tuples::tuple,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>)'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   T=boost::compute::float4_ 1>          ] 1> 
>   C:\workspaces\compute_test\src\demo.cpp(45): note: see reference to
>   function template instantiation 'OutputIterator
>   boost::compute::transform,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::compute::lambda::expression>(InputIterator1,InputIterator1,InputIterator2,OutputIterator,BinaryOperator,boost::compute::command_queue
>   &)' being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   OutputIterator=boost::compute::buffer_iterator, 1>
>   T=boost::compute::float4_, 1>
>   Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr,0>>,const
>   boost::compute::lambda::expression>,0>>
>   &,const
>   boost::compute::lambda::expression>,0>>
>   &>,3>, 1>
>   InputIterator1=boost::compute::buffer_iterator,
>   1>
>   InputIterator2=boost::compute::buffer_iterator,
>   1>
>   BinaryOperator=boost::compute::lambda::expression,0>>,const
>   boost::compute::lambda::expression>,0>>
>   &,const
>   boost::compute::lambda::expression>,0>>
>   &>,3>> 1>          ]
>   1>C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(68):
>   error C2668: 'boost::compute::make_zip_iterator': ambiguous call to
>   overloaded function 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp(276):
>   note: could be
>   'boost::compute::zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>
>   boost::compute::make_zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>(IteratorTuple)'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   T=boost::compute::float4_, 1>
>   IteratorTuple=boost::tuples::tuple,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>
>   1>          ] 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp(357): note: or
>   'boost::iterators::zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>
>   boost::iterators::make_zip_iterator,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>>(IteratorTuple)'
>   [found using argument-dependent lookup] 1>          with 1>          [
>   1>              T=boost::compute::float4_, 1>
>   IteratorTuple=boost::tuples::tuple,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>
>   1>          ] 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(68): note:
>   while trying to match the argument list
>   '(boost::tuples::tuple,boost::compute::buffer_iterator,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type>)'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   T=boost::compute::float4_ 1>          ]
>   1>C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(72):
>   error C2672: 'transform': no matching overloaded function found
>   1>C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(72):
>   error C2780: 'OutputIterator
>   boost::compute::transform(InputIterator1,InputIterator1,InputIterator2,OutputIterator,BinaryOperator,boost::compute::command_queue
>   &)': expects 6 arguments - 4 provided 1> 
>   C:\local\boost_1_67_0\boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp(55): note:
>   see declaration of 'boost::compute::transform'
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded,
>
> 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: If you think it's a bug, you could open a bug at boost: https://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html or try to get help by using one of the mailing lists : https://www.boost.org/community/groups.html (to check if it's a bug or not).

Comment: Posted the the mailing lists, thanks.

Comment: One of the most common bugs in C++ template code. Most people are not even aware of how broken argument dependent lookup in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short term fix is to modify `boost/compute/algorithm/transform.hpp`. Change both of the calls to `make_zip_iterator` to `::boost::compute::make_zip_iterator`. This qualifies the call to avoid argument dependent look up.

Update: This is fixed in [#790](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/pull/790)